# Presto not returning 0 on count

Tags: sql, presto

I have the following query:

```
with dates as (SELECT CAST(date_column AS DATE) DAY
FROM (
      VALUES (SEQUENCE(cast('2019-10-29' AS date), current_date, INTERVAL '1' DAY))) AS t1(date_array)
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(date_array) AS t2(date_column))

SELECT p.profile_id, coalesce(ct,0) AS ct, DAY
FROM connect_profiles p
left JOIN
(SELECT profile_id, COUNT(distinct visit_id) as ct, dates.DAY
 FROM connect_visits v right join dates on dates.DAY = cast(v.visit_created_at as date)
 where web_site_id in ('10','11') 
 and metadata like '%logged%' 
 GROUP BY profile_id, dates.DAY) CountQuery

ON p.profile_id = CountQuery.profile_id

where p.profile_id = 733194
order by DAY asc
```

I've tried everything I found on internet to help me return 0 on the count() when there is no visit for the profile_id, but I just don't know what I'm doing wrong. It just shows me the days the profile has visits, but I want everything in that date interval.

Can anybody help me?

That's the result I have:

```
 profile_id ct  DAY
1   733194  4   2019-11-04
2   733194  9   2019-11-06
3   733194  6   2019-11-07
4   733194  3   2019-11-09
5   733194  101 2019-11-10
6   733194  38  2019-11-11
7   733194  16  2019-11-12
8   733194  6   2019-11-14
9   733194  3   2019-11-17
10  733194  5   2019-11-18
11  733194  5   2019-11-19
12  733194  3   2019-11-20
13  733194  6   2019-11-21
14  733194  3   2019-11-22
15  733194  1   2019-11-23
16  733194  4   2019-11-24
17  733194  7   2019-11-25
18  733194  5   2019-11-26
19  733194  3   2019-11-27
20  733194  4   2019-11-28
21  733194  4   2019-11-30
22  733194  4   2019-12-01
23  733194  6   2019-12-02
24  733194  6   2019-12-03
25  733194  7   2019-12-05
26  733194  1   2019-12-06
27  733194  4   2019-12-07
28  733194  2   2019-12-08
29  733194  8   2019-12-09
30  733194  5   2019-12-10
31  733194  6   2019-12-11
32  733194  2   2019-12-12
33  733194  1   2019-12-13
34  733194  2   2019-12-14
35  733194  2   2019-12-15
36  733194  2   2019-12-16
```

I want the count since 2019-10-29, so if the person doesn't have visits, it shows me 0.

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text, not images. And make it easy to assist you, simplify - [mcve].

Comment: It would really help if you described what you are trying to do, along with sample data and desired results.

Comment: ok. just did it. is it better now?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
COUNT(IsNull(distinct visit_id),0)
```

Comment: there is no function IsNull on presto :(